# maybeDeferred analog with asyncio

Tags: python, twisted, future, coroutine, python-asyncio

I am coding a framework, where the framework will call a user-supplied function.

I want to allow the used supplied function to be any of the following:

- a plain function
- a function returning `asyncio.Future`
- a `asyncio.coroutine`

That is, the user function can be either synchronous or asynchronous, and the framework does not know in advance, but needs to cope with all variants.

Twisted [has](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.maybeDeferred.html) `defer.maybeDeferred` for this. What would be the `asyncio` way?

I have something like the following (**full code [here](https://github.com/oberstet/scratchbox/blob/master/python/asyncio/test3.py)**):

```
import types
types.GeneratorType

def maybe_async(value):
   if isinstance(value, types.GeneratorType) or \
      isinstance(value, asyncio.futures.Future):
      return value
   else:
      future = asyncio.Future()
      future.set_result(value)
      return future
```

and then call the user supplied function `f` like this in the framework:

```
res = yield from maybe_async(f(x))
```

This wraps any plain function return value into a `Future` - **always**. And I am wary of the performance or other impacts of this.

Is above the "recommended" way?

Also, the ["inline" version of above code](https://github.com/oberstet/scratchbox/blob/master/python/asyncio/test3.py#L89) does not have this overhead. How could I achieve the best of both: no overhead for the "plain" case, but no code duplication for checking for async returns all over the framework?

Comment: `maybeDeferred` accepts a function instead of the result of the function for a reason.  What do you want to happen if `f` raises a synchronous exception?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone catch it (the same for all variants): https://github.com/oberstet/scratchbox/blob/master/python/asyncio/test3.py#L96

Comment: `res = yield from asyncio.coroutine(f)(x)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian This works (also)! Could you expand on differences in what happens under the hood and performance / other impacts comparing these 3 variants https://github.com/oberstet/scratchbox/blob/master/python/asyncio/test3.py#L89 - Perhaps in an answer? That would be awesome!

Comment: @oberstet: I've just looked at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dfe327390cc2/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#l70). Variant #1 and #3 are essentially the same.

Comment: Awesome!! So I will use what you suggested. Thanks for the source pointer!

Answer (score 2):

To sum up, there seem to be two (main) options:

**Idiom 1:**

```
res = f(x)
if yields(res):
   res = yield from res
```

where

```
def yields(value):
   return isinstance(value, asyncio.futures.Future) or inspect.isgenerator(value)
```

or

**Idiom 2:**

```
res = yield from asyncio.coroutine(f)(x)
```

Comment: unrelated: you could use `asyncio.Future` name instead of `asyncio.futures.Future`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of isinstance(value, types.GeneratorType), you can write asyncio.iscoroutine(value):
https://docs.python.org/dev/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.iscoroutine